# Plotting a Pandas Framework from a CSV File

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, csv, matplotlib

Good morning everyone,

Basically, I am doing a Dataframe to the number of won in a lottery here where I live. I am stuck in plotting a Dataframe that I created from a CSV file. This is my code:

```
    data_file = pd.read_csv('Jugadas_Ganadas.csv')
    data_file.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data_file)
    pickle_out = open('Pega3_Ganados.pickle', 'wb')
    pickle.dump(df, pickle_out)
    pickle_out.close()

    fi = plt.figure()
    ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((1, 1), (0, 0))


    data_analysis = pd.read_pickle('Pega3_Ganados.pickle')

    print data_analysis
```

After printing the data analysis I get the following framework.

```
               Values
    Date             
    15/07/2017  [660]
    16/07/2017   [40]
    17/07/2017  [300]
    18/07/2017   [40]
    19/07/2017   [80]
```

After I confirm that I have a framework into my variable I try to plot it in a matplotlib graph by using this script.

```
    fi = plt.figure()
    ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((1, 1), (0, 0))

    data_analysis['Values'].plot(ax=ax1, label='Ganadas')
    plt.legend(loc=4)
    plt.show()
```

However, I get the following error:

**TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think column `values` contains lists, so need select first value of lists by `str[0]` :

```
print (type(df.loc[df.index[0], 'Values']))
<class 'list'>

data_analysis['Values'].str[0].plot(ax=ax1, label='Ganadas')
```

If type of values is `string` use [`strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) and [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
print (type(df.loc[df.index[0], 'Values']))
<class 'str'>

data_analysis['Values'].str.strip('[]').astype(int).plot(ax=ax1, label='Ganadas')
```

Comment: Thanks jezrael, Yes it is a string barely noticed it. I am new using Pandas Framework so I am still learning the syntax of Pandas. Again, thanks for the help!

Comment: I did already! I am new to stackoverflow but I did click the check sign. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Just to confirm what was the issue in this case. The main issue was that it could not plot the framework because the datatype was a string and since I converted the rows to integers using the astype method then it recognized the datatype and it was able to plot it into a graph.

Answer (score 0):

```
print (type(df.loc[df.index[0], 'Values']))
<class 'str'>

data_analysis['Values'].str.strip('[]').astype(int).plot(ax=ax1, label='Ganadas')
```

This should I tried it in my code too.